# When i run my application to my android, nothing is showing up except my blue background?

Tags: android, xml, string, button

I set up a blue background(which is showing up) 3 buttons and A text. I get no error for anything. I am using Eclipse. Heres the code for the file with the buttons

http://codepad.org/PHXom2bb
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Thanks

Comment: On the emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: Can you post your java code too?

Comment: ALL I Have is xml code.... thats all i wrote

Comment: Why not post the code here instead of a link to an external site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it has something to do with the positioning of the buttons. Try using relative positioning.

Comment: LOl how? and i used the margin function in the graphical layout...

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you can also see visually what you do.

the "fill_parent", makes the textview, or button to take all possible space it can.
And the "wrap_content", make it shrink as much as it can.

So check carefully what you put on those values.

You can see what your xml code does in Eclipse, without installing the app to your device.